# Drupal - PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: mysql, pdo, drupal

This is a problem with my Drupal website which shows this errors when I do a search.

Can someone help me?

Thank you so much

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'mysite/_drupal7_2013.search_config_exclude' doesn't exist:
>   SELECT SUM(i.score * t.count) AS calculated_score FROM {search_index}
>   i INNER JOIN {node} n ON n.nid = i.sid INNER JOIN {search_total} t ON
>   i.word = t.word LEFT OUTER JOIN {search_config_exclude} sc ON n.nid =
>   sc.entity_id AND sc.entity_type = :type WHERE (n.status =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND( (i.word =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_1) )AND (i.type =
>   :db_condition_placeholder_2) AND (n.nid NOT IN
>   (:db_condition_placeholder_3)) AND (sc.entity_id IS NULL ) GROUP BY
>   i.type, i.sid HAVING (COUNT(*) >= :matches) ORDER BY calculated_score
>   DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => asdasdasd
>   [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => node [:db_condition_placeholder_3] =>
>   0 [:matches] => 1 [:type] => node ) in SelectQueryExtender->__call()
>   (line 841 of
>   /home/mysite/public_html/mysite.com/includes/database/select.inc).

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/quant/issues/1749360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this error i.e.

```
> Table 'mysite/_drupal7_2013.search_config_exclude' doesn't exist
```

Either your database is not having this table or your search functionality code is having fault.
Please share your site link if possible.

> For more technical articles or help, have a look at
>   http://etutorialz.com